# oracle string replace odd number of slash at the end of string

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle pl sql how to add one SLASH if a field ends with ODD NUMBER OF SLASH?

For example for a column c I want:

```
    AAA\ converts to AAA\\
    AAA do nothing
    AAA\\ do nothing
    AAA\\\ converts to AAA\\\\
    AAA\\\\ do nothing
    AAA\\\\\ converts to AAA\\\\\\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, `LENGTH` and `MOD` functions as follows:

```
SELECT YOUR_COLUMN, 
       CASE WHEN MOD(LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YOUR_COLUMN,'[\]+$')),2) = 1 
            THEN YOUR_COLUMN || '\' 
       ELSE YOUR_COLUMN 
       END AS RESULT
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```